# html5 video continue preload when paused

Tags: html, html5-video

In my website page has a media player to load media stream through `<video>` tag.

I already gave `<video preload='auto'>` an attribute but when I paused video playing which will to stop preload.

So how to continue preload media stream when user trigger pause event (like Vimeo or Youtube) ?

Comment: YT uses [MSI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). But for your case, can't you let the browser do what it thinks is the best for your user?

Comment: Can you give us the full code of the video tag ? and which browser you are tesing in ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a video from sites like youtube and vimeo, it's better if you load the source of those url into your page through an iframe so that it will automatically adjust what it thinks is  best for the user, like pre-loads the video when paused.

```
<iframe width="320" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/petB-pNCudc" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: He is using <video> tag for his own uploaded videos, not iframe for embedding youtube like videos!